# Sybase jdbc4 not returning any results from sql query

Tags: java, sybase

I'm trying to run a query against a Sybase database. It seems like the connection is made successfully but when it hits rs.next() it fails to go to the first row in the results.  It jumps down to the rs.Close().

I know for a fact that my query below works. I'm running it in a sql tool and it returns one record.

Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import java.sql.*;
import com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource;
import com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver;


public class test { 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
       SybDriver sybDriver = null;
       Connection conn = null;
       Statement stmt = null;
       String host = "123.12.34.56";
       String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:"+host+":1300";
       String username = "testuser";
       String password ="password";

       try{
           sybDriver=(SybDriver)Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
           stmt = conn.createStatement();
           ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select top 1 brand, model,color,serialnum from myTable order by newid()");

           while(rs.next())
           {
              String one = rs.getString(1);
              String two = rs.getString(2);
              String three = rs.getString(3);
              String four = rs.getString(4);
           }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch(SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You know your while block "does nothing" (some var are set but thrown away). Can you clarify what do you mean by "jump" (i.e. how do you know there is a "jump")?

Comment: @RC It hits the, "while(rs.next())" line which I thought would set the record set to the first result row (and then iterate through the remaining results) and then I could pull the information out.

Comment: So your issue is `rs.next` is returning false? If so it means there's nothing to read, maybe some "user rights" issue

Comment: @RC yes, rs.next is returning false and I don't know why.  I'm using the same userId in my sql query tool and it returns the result correctly.

Comment: AFAIK, your java code is OK (note that you should make sure the close are executed with a classic try-catch-finally or a try with resource), so the issue is elsewhere. Can you try with the getMetaData part commented out (just to be sure)

Comment: @RC I deleted that metadata part out completely.  Still not getting any results.

Comment: `jdbc:sybase:Tds:host:port/database` is the format of the URL string that jdbc uses to connect to sybase DB. You're obviously missing the database name.

Comment: @JanezKuhar You are correct!  That's what I was missing!